# Replace continuous space with single space and multiple "&nbsp" elements

Tags: html, c#-2.0, space

I have one html document which contains whitespaces in some nodes. For example,

```
<B>This is          Whitespace      Node </B>
```

When this html is displayed in the browser, more than one continuous space in html is always displayed as one space. To avoid this issue, I want to replace the continuous spaces with a single space and multiple `&nbsp;` elements.

What is the best solution to achive this?

I am using C# 2005.

Comment: Just a note: if you didn't have the opening and closing `<b>` tags, you could use HttpServerUtility().HtmlEncode().

Comment: Suggestion: always close your HTML Entities with the ending semicolon: `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
string str = "<B>This is          Whitespace      Node </B>";
Regex rgx = new Regex("([\\S][ ])");
string result = rgx.Replace(str, "$1.")
                        .Replace(" .","?")
                        .Replace(" ","&nbsp")
                        .Replace("?"," ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS's `white-space` property as per http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop

```
white-space: pre-wrap
```

---

Or, if you really want to do it with bruteforce, replace two consecutive spaces with a non-breaking-space and a normal space... I strongly recommend against this.

```
string text = originalText.Replace("  ", "&nbsp; ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
String.Replace("  ", " ")
```

if you prefer regex

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("([ \t]|&nsbp)+");
string result = rgx.Replace(input, " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are setting the value of the control from code behind? If so then ...

```
<strong><asp:Literal id="myLiteral">This is          Whitespace      Node </asp:Literal></strong>
```

And in code behind ...

```
var myText = "This is          Whitespace      Node ";
myLiteral.Text = myText.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
```

If no code behind or not in a literal ...

```
<strong><%= "This is          Whitespace      Node ".Replace(" ", "&nbsp;") %></strong>
```

Comment: Also the <B> tag is deprecated ... use <strong>